# What is the "Data Language" paper referenced in RFC 309?

Tags: history, internet, documentation

[RFC 309](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc309) is an announcement of the 1972 Data and File Transfer Workshop announcement. The suggested reading section has 12 entries, 11 of which are RFCs and the last of which is:

> ```
>              8. Data Language, CCA,  NIC # 8208
> ```

This document appears difficult to find.

> The one non-RFC document is a publication called “Data Language” by Computer Corporation of America, but I can't find something with that exact name online to link.
> — Darius Kazemi, [RFC-309 — 365 RFCs](https://write.as/365-rfcs/rfc-309)

What is this paper? Who was it written by, when was it published and where can it be found?

Comment: @Michael NIC numbers were assigned by the Network Information Center, see [RFC 95](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc95). NIC was run by the Stanford Research Institute, then by Network Solutions (where it became InterNIC), and then its responsibilities were transferred to ICANN (in 1998).

Answer (score 15):

[RFC565](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc565.txt) identifies NIC 8208 as: `Computer Corporation of America, Datacomputer Project Working Paper No. 3, Datalanguage, 29 Oct '71, 78 pp.`

A copy of this document is available in the online repository of the US DoD's [Defense Technical Information Center](http://www.dtic.mil/) in a pdf document titled "[Semi-Annual Technical Report, March 1972](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/741263.pdf#page=6)". Working Paper No. 3 is bundled with Working Paper No. 4 in the same file.

Comment: Is NIC 8208 related in any way to ISO 8208?

Comment: @JonCuster - ISO 8208 is the X.25 level 3 protocol; this doc seems to be a data definition language which, if forced into the OSI model, would probably operate at level 6.

Comment: @another-dave - OK, thanks! I thought it worth querying just in case.